# How to display ReadOnlyFields without label in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I am trying to display some data in my Django admin `ReadOnlyFields`, but I am unable to display, I want to display `emailid` and `verify_emailid` in the same line in the fields, I can do it using `fieldset` but it's displaying lable also, please let me know how I can display data without a table.

Here is my `admin.py` file...

```
class MyModelAdmin(ReadOnlyAdminMixin, CustomModelAdmin):
  fields = (('emailid','verify_emailid),'mobilenumber','type')
```

here `emailid` and `verify_emailid` display in the same line but the issue is the `verify_emailid` display label, and I don't want the label of `verify_emailid`, please let me know how I can remove the `verify_emailid` label...

Answer (score 0):

If you want complete control of the text for a particular line, you could add a method to control that line, and then add that method as a readonly field:

#### Solution

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

class MyModelAdmin(ReadOnlyAdminMixin, CustomModelAdmin):
  fields = ('my_custom_line','mobilenumber','type')

  def my_custom_line(self, instance):
     return format_html('<p>{} {}</p>', instance.emailid, instance.verify_emailid)
```

#### How does the solution work

Any method on `ModelAdmin` class that returns some text, can be used as a readonly field. You can read more about this in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields).

`format_html` is just a safe way of inserting html, to avoid various attacks. The values listed after the html are inserted into the html as would normally happen. You can edit this line anyway you like to get the desired affect. You can read about that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html).

Answer (score 0):

base on django 3.2

at first you can custom and Override the admin html template.

Let's take a look at how the template file is .

`~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form.html`

```html
# line 48
{% block field_sets %}
{% for fieldset in adminform %}
    {% include "admin/includes/fieldset.html" %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
# line 52
```

`~/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/includes/fieldset.html`

```html
# line 12
{% if field.is_checkbox %}
    {{ field.field }}{{ field.label_tag }}
{% else %}
    {{ field.label_tag }}  # the label tag is here !
    {% if field.is_readonly %}
        <div class="readonly">{{ field.contents }}</div>
    {% else %}
        {{ field.field }}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
# line 21
```

of cause, you can Override this template, but I don't do this.

I want `field.label_tag()` return **empty string** or some thing you want to achieve your goal.

so let's use Monkey Patching!

```py
# admin.py
from django.contrib.admin.helpers import AdminReadonlyField

old_label_tag = AdminReadonlyField.label_tag

def new_label_tag(self):
    hide_label = ['verify_emailid']
    if self.field['name'] in hide_label:
        return format_html('')
    else:
        return old_label_tag(self)

AdminReadonlyField.label_tag = new_label_tag
```

`AdminReadonlyField.label_tag()` has been modified.if the field name within
your select the label_tag will return empty string Others return normal label tag.